# Question up for 1 hour and all comments disappeared

Tags: support

I was getting what I thought was negative feedback on a [question that I had asked an hour ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1259663/tether-from-windows-to-other-device-over-usb), and I made an edit to as an attempt to correct myself about 10 minutes ago. The moment I posted the edit all comments from all users on the question disappeared. I'm not sure if they were flagged, deleted, magically abducted by a greedy cyber-leprechaun at large, or maybe I am hallucinating and need to get professional help.

I'm pretty sure this is a non-issue, but if it is not too much to ask for, can someone with privileges take a look for me and confirm I am not developing schizophrenia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments were between you and I alone.  I chose to delete my comments as they were unhelpful and apparently not what you were looking for.

As a result your comments lacked context and were no longer relevant so were removed as well.

See the [comment privilege page](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment) which states:

> ## What are comments?
>
> Comments are **temporary "Post-It" notes** left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I was unaware that comments don't generate reputation. I question the ethics of not being informed of when comments are deleted. No accountability, and I was genuinely questioning my sanity (schiz, is genetic in my family, and I haven't quite made it through my twenties yet). I know there was a post somewhere in here about those kind of notifications. I want to add those (my) thoughts to it.

Comment: @DaMaxContent https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11838/can-i-get-notified-when-my-comment-is-deleted